# Double Domain in WordPress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently merged databases in WordPress and now my content is getting multiple domains in it's url.

For example it should be http://www.example.com/content

but it is http://www.example.com/www.example.com/content

My settings show:
WordPress Address (URL) http://www.example.com/
Site Address (URL) http://www.example.com/

I haven't made any changes to HTACCESS

Answer (score 1):

by hardcoding

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
```

into wp-config.php I was able to solve this issue.

Comment: Even this solved your issue, it is important to mention that this is far away from proper or solution which should be applied. During database migration from one domain to another you need to preform updates on database with the new domain (so everything can be loaded properly). With options above you are just going to "overide" options stored within database (in this case, wp_prefix_option table -> site_url and home), and you will not change it within database. Additionally if you have hard coded links within your post contents or widgets (which usually happen), all those will be broken.

Comment: I did preform database updates. I'm not sure what the cause of this specific bug was, I just know the solution. If you know the cause of the bug, please specify.

Comment: You did not update your database properly. That is the source of the bug. What kind of option you have within wp_options table for option_name "home" ??

Comment: "not properly" is not specific enough of an answer

Comment: You are aware that things you are saying are mutually exclusive? You are saying that your database fields have proper values, and then as solution you are overriding those values??? So if I say that values you have in database are not OK that is not specific enough for you?? Anyway, there is no make sense to continue with discussion. Reason i posted the comment is for sake of future readers (so they dont stumble upon on different issues applying same solution).

Answer (score 0):

As @cool suggested, you have to check wp_options table for option name "home" (probably "siteurl" too, since you have the same).

**Save the options prepended with "http://".**

Like http://www.example.com. You have them saved as www.example.com as seen from your question:

> but it is http://www.example.com/www.example.com/content